# Qual a diferença ao chamar uma função com parênteses e sem no urls.py com Django 1.7?

Tags: python, orientação-a-objetos, django, funções, view

No mapeamento do meu urls.py eu utilizo desde funções comuns até views baseadas em classes.

Quero saber qual a diferença de chamar a view com ou sem parênteses, tendo em vista que se eu tenho a entrada `url(r'^$', base_views.index_view)`, colocar os parênteses ao chamar a função correspondente (que na declaração recebe apenas um objeto *request*) lança um *TypeError* com a seguinte mensagem: **index_view() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'**.

Já na entrada `url(r'^authors/$', AuthorViews.AuthorView.as_view)`, quando removo os parênteses ele lança o mesmo erro citado acima com a mensagem: **as_view() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given**.

Eu entendo que o problema é que ao chamar uma das funções, os argumentos da mesma  não são supridos  como na declaração, mas, não entendo como a função url do Django passa esses parâmetros nem porque os parênteses fazem diferença.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Basicamente uma "view" é uma função que recebe uma requisição (resquest) e retorna uma resposta (response).

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
import datetime

def index_view(request):
    now = datetime.datetime.now()
    html = "<html><body>It is now %s.</body></html>" % now
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

As views são então mapeadas no URLConf do Django. Exemplo abaixo:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url

from . import views

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index_view, name='principal'),
    url(r'^autores/$', views.AuthorView.as_view(), name='autores')
    ...
)
```

O Django faz a correspondência entre a url que o usuário acessa e as
expressões regulares das urls na URLConf, executando a "view" que está mapeada de acordo.

Para essa "view" são passados os seguintes argumentos:
1 - Uma instância de HttpRequest.
2 - Argumentos que vem da URL
3 - Argumentos extras opcionais.

A função url() segue o seguinte padrão.

```
url(regex, view, kwargs=None, name=None, prefix='')
```

O Django é que fará a chamada da "view" e passará os argumentos corretamente.
Logo você deve passa o callable e não a chamada da função.
"index_view" (callable) é diferente de "index_view(request)".

No tocante a Class Based Views você vai precisar executar o método as_view para
'transformar' sua CBV em uma view. CBView.as_view() retorna um callable.

```
response = CBView.as_view()(request)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/urls/#url
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/class-based-views/base/#django.views.generic.base.View.as_view

Comment: Agora tudo faz sentido. Não tinha me ligado que o as_view retornava um callable, então é por isso que temos que executá-la: para receber um objeto que a função url vai chamar e enviar os parâmetros para ele.

Answer (score 3):

O que está acontecendo lá dentro do código da função url é algo mais ou menos assim:

```
def url(regex, view):
    request = make_request()
    view(request)
```

O parâmetro view é uma função que recebe um request. A função url passa o request para a função view.

Quando você chama o método view sem parâmetros você obtém o erro que você mencionou pois você está passando um parâmetro a menos do que o esperado. Já quando você omite os parênteses você na verdade não está chamando o método, você está apenas criando um "bound method", que é equivalente a você ter escrito

```
url(r'^$', (lambda req: base_views.index_view(req))
```

Como você pode ver, não estamos chamando o método view - estamos apenas passando pra função url uma função que chama o view.

Answer (score 3):

Quando você associa uma URL a uma *view* você não está chamando a função da *view* - apenas indicando **qual** função deverá ser chamada quando alguém visitar aquela URL. Em outras palavras, ao fazer:

```
url(r'^$', base_views.index_view)
```

Você está armazenando, em algum lugar, uma referência para `index_view`. Essa referência será em algum outro momento (pois aqui nenhuma requisição está sendo feita) chamada passando-se como argumento um *request*.

Se você tentar chamar essa função nesse momento:

1. Sem parâmetros não vai funcionar, pois ela espera um *request*;
2. Com um parâmetro do tipo *request* ela pode funcionar, mas aí ela vai retornar um `HttpResponse` ou similar - e isso não ajuda nada na hora que as requisições verdadeiras forem feitas (pois é necessário saber qual função chamar nesse momento).

Já no outro caso, `AuthorViews.AuthorView` é um objeto, não uma função. Não basta usar ele próprio no `urls.py`, pois é preciso saber qual função chamar durante uma requisição, e é pra isso que serve o `as_view` - ele retorna uma função apropriada para ser associada àquela URL. **É uma função que retorna outra função**. Por isso precisa ser chamada.

Se você não chama, o Django acha que *ela* é que é a *view*, então tenta chamá-la passando um *request*. Como ela já é um *bound method* (pois ao fazer `AuthorView.as_view` ele "ligou" a função ao seu objeto), o parâmetro implícito `self` já está setado. O segundo parâmetro - um `HttpRequest` - é inesperado, daí ele reclama de ter recebido um parâmetro a mais.